# MulticastDelegate in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm using MulticastDelegate class which is part of **xmpp framework** and taken [here](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/trunk/MulticastDelegate.h) It works perfect for me! However I got warning:

> 'MulticastDelegate' may not respond to
>   'someMethod'

Is there any way to avoid the warning for this class? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link to the multicast delegate header is dead.  Here is a link to the wiki page: http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/MulticastDelegate.  I couldn't find the old class, but browsing through the source I found a new class based on GCD:  http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/Utilities/GCDMulticastDelegate.h

Comment: I was unable to find the `MulticastDelegate` referenced in this question - so have built my own here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/11/a-multicast-delegate-pattern-for-ios-controls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of `someMethod` is that? Did you include the `MulticastDelegate.h` header?

---

*Update:* Aha, in that case you need to tell the compiler that the delegate implements the `Notifier` interface:

```
#import "MulticastDelegate.h"

@protocol Notifier
- (void) someMethod; 
@end

@interface Manager
{
   MulticastDelegate <Notifier> delegate;
}
@end
```

This should do. But isn’t the code a bit fishy? How do you know that the `delegate` implements `someMethod` when `delegate` is a plain `MulticastDelegate`? Are you omitting something in the example?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have imported `"MulticastDelegate.h"` and someMethode is part of the public interface of the class as declared in `"MulticastDelegate.h"`, you shouldn't get this warning.

GCC issues this warning only on the ocassion you send a message to an object which does not publicly declare to respond to that message.

Answer (score 0):

I have a protocol

```
@protocol Notifier
 -(void) someMethod; 
@end
```

and class

```
#import "MulticastDelegate.h"

@interface Manager
{
       MulticastDelegate delegate; 
}
@end
```

somewhere in the implementation file

```
delegate= [[MulticastDelegate alloc] init];
.....
- (void)addDelegate:(id)_delegate
{
    [delegate addDelegate:_delegate];
}
```

and then

```
[delegate someMethod];
```

Line above causes the warning I mentioned in my question.

> 'MulticastDelegate' may not respond to
>   'someMethod'